# ¿Como puedo modificar el template contact.html para mostrar un mensaje de error?

Tags: python, django

Quiero que parezca un mensaje de error por ejemplo: **"El mail no se ha enviado. Pruebe de nuevo"** para indicar que algo ha fallado. Como sucede cuando no hay ningún problema y se envía el mail con **"Su mensaje se ha enviado correctamente, en breve nos pondremos en contacto con usted."**

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Contacto{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!-- Contacto -->
<section class="page-section about-heading">
  <div class="container">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded about-heading-img mb-3 mb-lg-0" src="{% static 'core/img/contact.jpg' %}" alt="">
    <div class="about-heading-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 col-lg-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="bg-faded rounded p-5">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
              <span class="section-heading-upper">Envíanos tus dudas</span>
              <span class="section-heading-lower">Contacto</span>
            </h2>

            <!-- Formulario de contacto -->
            {% if 'ok' in request.GET %}
              <p><b>Su mensaje se ha enviado correctamente, en breve nos pondremos en contacto con usted.</b><p>
            {% endif %}
            {% if 'fail' in request.GET %}
              <p><b>No sé pudo enviar el mensaje. Intente de nuevo por favor.</b></p>
            {% endif %}  
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Nombre *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form.name}}
                    </div>
                    {{form.name.errors}}
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form.email}}
                    </div>
                    {{form.email.errors}}
                    <!--<ul class="errorlist">
                        <li>El email no es correcto.</li>
                    </ul>-->
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Mensaje *</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        {{form.content}}
                    </div>
                    {{form.content.errors}}
                </div>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block py-2" value="Enviar">
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- Fin formulario de contacto -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

y dejo el código de views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from .forms import ContactForm

# Create your views here.
def contact(request):
    contact_form = ContactForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        contact_form = ContactForm(data=request.POST)
        if contact_form.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name', '')
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            content = request.POST.get('content', '')
            # Enviamos el correo y redireccionamos
            email = EmailMessage(
                "La Caffettiera: Nuevo mensaje de contacto",
                "De {} <{}>\n\nEscribió:\n\n{}".format(name, email, content),
                "no-contestar@inbox.mailtrap.io",
                ["django@hektorprofe.net"],
                reply_to=[email]
            )

            try:
                email.send()
                # Todo ha ido bien, redireccionamos a OK
                return redirect(reverse('contact')+"?ok")
            except:
                # Algo no ha ido bien, redireccionamos a FAIL
                return redirect(reverse('contact')+"?fail")

    return render(request, "contact/contact.html", {'form':contact_form})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Te sugiero que revises la documentacion oficial, aqui tienes el link 
<link>https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/messages/</link>
o mira si esto te puede servir: Archivo html
<code>
{% load static %}
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/login.css' %}">
    <body id="body">
    {% if messages %}
        <ul class="message">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <script>
             alert('{{ message|capfirst }}');
             window.location.href='/';
            </script>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Clave">
        <a href="/">Ir al inicio</a>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Acceder">
    </form>
    </body>
</code>
Archivo py>
 <code>
    def login(request):
        message = ''
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            auth_user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if auth_user is not None and auth_user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, auth_user)
                #return HttpResponse("Usted se    ha registrado en el sitio")
                HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                messages.success(request, "Usted se ha autenticado en el sistema")
            else:
                HttpResponseRedirect('//')
                messages.error(request, "Clave o usuario incorrecto")
         return render(request,
                      template_name='login.html',
                      context={
                          'message': message,
                               })
</code>
```

Comment: Puedes adaptarlo al tuyo aunque sean diferentes funciones